Connect BMS to a battery pack of three 18650 cells connected in parallel
I’ve assembled a battery pack using three 18650 cells connected in parallel to power a circuit that requires 3.7V but with extended battery life.
I wanted to ensure the cells are protected, especially against incorrect polarity insertion. I wired the circuit according to the following image, but it seems there’s a problem. When I tested it by inserting a cell with reversed polarity, I saw a spark and some smoke, indicating that it’s not functioning as intended.
I’m having trouble finding wiring diagrams or instructions for BMS boards used with cells connected in parallel.
What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?
Thanks in advance!

These are the BMS
And this is the wiring:


We don't know what BMSes those are and how they function. If one battery was empty and one battery is full, tens of amps could flow. Did you balance out the batteries before connecting them directly together?

I added the BMS I am using

OK, now we know what BMSes those are. How do they function then?

Added the wiring of those modules

The description mentions nothing about wrong polarity protection. So you tried what happens if you connect a cell upside down to the BMS board? Or the BMS board upside down to another BMS board? Please be specific what you did to emit the smoke. And this is the reason why devices don't have user replaceable cells - are you designing something with user replaceable cells or the whole pack?

Oh, I see. I just assumed polarity protection was there, part of the "protection" statement. The batteries are gonna be replaceable by me, but just to make sure that everything was as safe as possible.

The parallel groups are treated as single cells.  Fuses can protect from reversal smoke.

The BMSes you use don't have reverse battery insertion protection.
This is exactly the reason no such commercial devices exist (or at least should not exist) where you as a consumer are able to insert batteries with incorrect polarity to a BMS.
Lithium batteries require everything around them to be designed for safety so no bad things can happen accidentally.
For replaceable battery packs, it's the battery pack which which is built with BMS or at least with a connector you cannot connect incorrectly.
Do not design devices with batteries in parallel that are user replaceable.
Another unsafe example is when user first puts in an empty battery and then another full battery and large current flows from full battery to empty battery. Sure the BMS may cut out one of the batteries due to overcurrent, but then you have only one or two batteries connected.
The next thing to figure out is that are the BMSes you are using intended to be used like that. If the manual does noy say, you cannot be sure.
